# datetime data in R > ggplot2 : how to create x-axis breaks by hour

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am using 1 year worth of divvy bike sharing data (located [here](https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)) which includes the start time of rentals, and I am trying to make a histogram based on start time by hour with x-axis breaks major and minor breaks at 2 and 1 hour, respectively.

I started by taking the full start date + start time info and creating a new column for start time only where all the dates are set to 0000-01-01 with then accurate times.

```r
str(bike_trip_df$start_time)
POSIXct[1:6655120], format: "0000-01-01 17:15:49" "0000-01-01 17:23:14" "0000-01-01 02:34:23" "0000-01-01 06:52:55" "0000-01-01 11:55:29" "0000-01-01 12:41:12" "0000-01-01 12:21:50"
```

I then created the following histogram:

```r
ggplot(bike_trip_df, mapping = aes(x=start_time)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 24, color = "white", fill = "blue") +
  labs(
    title = "Usage by time of day", 
    subtitle = "Members vs Casual users", 
    x = "Ride start time", 
    y = "ride count") + 
  facet_wrap(~ member_casual) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_comma()) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M")
```

[image: image of the plot]

Up to this point, things are fine. What I can't figure out how to do is break my x-axis with major breaks at 2 hours, minor breaks at 1 hour. When I update to

```
scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "2 hours", date_labels = "%H:%M")
```

I get

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

My understanding is this means the function is not recognizing `"2 hours"` as a valid definition for the break, so am I just not understanding how this function works?

Additionally, I've tried messing with the formats of the `start_time` column, but other formats (chr, hms) make it so I can't create the plot at all because they invalidate the StatBin operation.

I've also tried using `axis.POSIXct(1, at = , format = "%H:%M")` instead of `scale_x_datetime`, but I can't figure out what to put in the `at =`  argument.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: If your time column is `POSIXlt`, try converting it to `POSIXct`.

Comment: The time column is ```POSIXct```

Comment: Odd ... I wonder where `as.POSIXlt.character` is coming from ...

Comment: fyi, `axis.POSIXct` is base graphics, not `ggplot2`.

Comment: I _think_ the ```as.POSIXlt.character``` is referring to ```"2 hours"``` in the code.  But the examples in help doc for ```?scale_x_datetime``` are "2 weeks" and "10 years", so "2 hours" seems to me like it should work.

Comment: Have you tried `scale_x_datetime(date_minor_breaks = "1 hour", date_breaks = "2 hours", date_labels = "%H:%M")`? It's a bit _tight_ on my screen, so it might benefit from something like `+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))`, or you can add `guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)` to `scale_x_datetime`.

Comment: (I suggest that because it works here on my console, so ... perhaps you originally had a typo, your data is not quite what is demonstrated above, or something else that I can't figure out.)

Comment: I tried copying your code back into mine, but I still get the same error. the ```str()``` print in my original question is directly from my code, so I know that part is ok. I don't understand what causes the error. I appreciate you looking at it for me, though.

Comment: I just loaded one of the CSVs from the first `zip` file, added `start_time = as.POSIXct(paste("0001-01-01", substring(started_at, 12)))`, and it plotted without error.

Comment: That worked! I'll have to go back and look into the process I used for converting the datetime to just time, because apparently that was my problem. When I used the paste function as you did, the error stopped. Running str() on the start_time column gave the exact same info in both cases, so I'm not sure what the deal is, but I'll investigate. Thanks for the help!

Comment: See my answer, I think that wraps up showing things, though I don't know that we solved what put you there in the first place. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of all of your calculation steps, but loading a subset of data, I can get it to work with:

```r
dat <- read.csv("202004-divvy-tripdata.csv")
dat[,3:4] <- lapply(dat[,3:4], function(z) as.POSIXct(paste("0001-01-01", substring(z, 12))))
head(dat)
#            ride_id rideable_type          started_at            ended_at                  start_station_name start_station_id            end_station_name end_station_id start_lat start_lng end_lat  end_lng member_casual
# 1 A847FADBBC638E45   docked_bike 0001-01-01 17:45:14 0001-01-01 18:12:03                        Eckhart Park               86 Lincoln Ave & Diversey Pkwy            152   41.8964  -87.6610 41.9322 -87.6586        member
# 2 5405B80E996FF60D   docked_bike 0001-01-01 17:08:54 0001-01-01 17:17:03           Drake Ave & Fullerton Ave              503             Kosciuszko Park            499   41.9244  -87.7154 41.9306 -87.7238        member
# 3 5DD24A79A4E006F4   docked_bike 0001-01-01 17:54:13 0001-01-01 18:08:36                McClurg Ct & Erie St              142  Indiana Ave & Roosevelt Rd            255   41.8945  -87.6179 41.8679 -87.6230        member
# 4 2A59BBDF5CDBA725   docked_bike 0001-01-01 12:50:19 0001-01-01 13:02:31        California Ave & Division St              216      Wood St & Augusta Blvd            657   41.9030  -87.6975 41.8992 -87.6722        member
# 5 27AD306C119C6158   docked_bike 0001-01-01 10:22:59 0001-01-01 11:15:54                Rush St & Hubbard St              125  Sheridan Rd & Lawrence Ave            323   41.8902  -87.6262 41.9695 -87.6547        casual
# 6 356216E875132F61   docked_bike 0001-01-01 17:55:47 0001-01-01 18:01:11 Mies van der Rohe Way & Chicago Ave              173     Streeter Dr & Grand Ave             35   41.8969  -87.6217 41.8923 -87.6120        member

gg <- ggplot(dat, mapping = aes(x=started_at)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 24, color = "white", fill = "blue") +
  labs(
    title = "Usage by time of day", 
    subtitle = "Members vs Casual users", 
    x = "Ride start time", 
    y = "ride count") + 
  facet_wrap(~ member_casual) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_comma())
```

Because of how closely things are spaced, I think you have two easy options for labelling the x-axis:

```r
gg +
  scale_x_datetime(
    date_minor_breaks = "1 hour", date_breaks = "2 hours",
    date_labels = "%H:%M",
    guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 3))
```

[image: ggplot using axis label dodging]

or

```r
gg +
  scale_x_datetime(
    date_minor_breaks = "1 hour", date_breaks = "2 hours",
    date_labels = "%H:%M") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image: ggplot using angled x axis labels]